# materializes CSS dropdown content not selected

Tags: html, materialize

Hope everything is fine.

Why my dropdown is not working always get drop me as selected

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dummy.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRAWebsiteV3.FrontEnd.dummy" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
     <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>
         Drop Me!
     </a>
      <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
      <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it is not working ?

Comment: can you add the library which you have used and try creating a demo

Comment: what u mean I have used this one  https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: @Allabakash what u mean I have used this one materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: @Allabakash any luck man

Comment: it is working as expected. what is the issue you are facing ? and can you add complete html code you are using ?

Comment: @Allabakash not working for me and console not showing any error I did complete the html code boss

Comment: I copy pasted the code shared by you, https://plnkr.co/edit/TNofPd8d5TwbrHdg?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview.  it is working.  can you elaborate about the issue you are facing ?

Comment: ok I thought when I select two, two should be shown as selected instead of drop me is this the normal behaviour of dropdown @Allabakash

Comment: @Allabakash any luck

Comment: It is the normal behavior, for your use case, either you need to use select or customize current component to show selected value

Comment: https://materializecss.com/select.html